# Increasing convex-like function in Hilbert space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am intersted with the differential equation

$$x'(t)=f(t,x(t)),\ t\in \mathbb{R}.$$
Can we find an example of a Hilbert space $H$ and a function $f:\mathbb{R}\times H \to H$ which satisfy the two conditions:

1) For all $x,y\in H$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$
$$<f(t,x)-f(t,y),x-y> \ \geq0.$$

2) If for some $x,y\in H$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$ 
$$<f(t,x)-f(t,y),x-y>=0,$$
then
$$f(t,x)=f(t,y)=f(t,\frac{x+y}{2}).$$

Answer (score 1):

The choice $f = 0$ satisfies your requirements.

In the case $H = \mathbb{R}$, your conditions are equivalent to $f$ being monotonically increasing.

Comment: I don't know if we can find nontrivial functions satisfying the condition 2) but with $$f(t,x)=f(t,y)=f(t,\frac{x+y}{2}).$$ without necessarily $x=y=\frac{x+y}{2}$.

Comment: If the function is not strictly monotonically increasing, you have, e.g., $f(0) = f(1)$. Or, take $f(x) = \max(0,x)$.